# Battery terminals, how hard is it OK to "force" terminal on there?

Tags: battery, battery-cable

I'm adding an aftermarket terminal to my battery so I can connect some other stuff while keeping the OEM connectors intact.  First, here's a picture the aftermarket terminal: [image: after market terminal]

And then, here's a picture of the OEM connector that I intend to put onto the brass post: [image]

Unfortunately, there is just hardly any slack in the OEM connections, and I can barely stretch them to connect to the new post.  In fact, it was a bit difficult to get them off the original battery post because there isn't much slack in the wires.  Since the new terminal adds about an inch of height, it gets even harder to connect them.

My question is, is it OK to have a wire connection like this that's putting strain on the battery terminal?  How strong are they?  I don't want to yank the battery terminal out or cause it to leak acid by pulling the battery cable too tight.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Personally, I'd have some misgivings about what you're trying to accomplish. While this is not a bad question, you should write a separate question about what you are trying to accomplish and to ask what is the best way of accomplishing it. Not knowing what your end goal is here, it seems like there is probably a better way of making it happen. If I get some time today, I'll write an answer to this question.

Comment: Are you sure the battery is the correct one for your vehicle?  Sometimes people substitute and it may fit but cause issues like this.  Generally you don't want the cables to be under tension as that can lead to breakage and reliability issues.  You could also see about getting some new cables made that are the correct length.

Comment: Thanks for the help!  Yes the battery is correct, since the car is newer and it's the one that came stock.  I'm pretty new to car maintenance stuff so I may just be being squirrelly about things.  As far as my goal, I'm just trying to attach a 4 gauge wire to the positive terminal for a aftermarket amp for the stereo.  The obvious thing is to crimp on a ring connector, but it looked like I'd need an expensive-ish tool to do a decent job, and so I bought that terminal I linked above instead.

Comment: It looks to me like your aftermarket post gives you a handy screw-on connection point for your 4AWG wire for the amp (silver screw on the side of the brass post), right? What's wrong with simply using any of the 3 studs on the OEM clamp with bolts on them? It won't _look_ quite as cool, but you get your bolt-on connection for the new wire without any stretching beyond what the factory intended.

Comment: @FreeMan That's exactly right.  I thought at the time it was also cheaper to buy the aftermarket post, instead of a tool to put a proper crimp for a ring connector.  I know you can crimp it with just a hammer and a screw driver, but I wanted to make sure it was sturdy and looked good too.  In the aftermarket post the additional 4AWG wire just screws in, so no crimp needed.  I've seen since then that you can buy a hammer crimp thing for $20 bucks, so $5 more than the aftermarket post.

Comment: Might be worth considering it "lesson learned", bite the bullet on the "wasted money", and getting the crimper. On the bright side, you've got some nice looking terminal adapters that you can repurpose for something else...